# localhost and AJAX/JQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am very new in AJAX/JQuery. I have problem with following thing. I am hoping to get some information and suggestion on following thing.
I have data real time generated data  (eg. xyz) in my localhost server which i have programmed using Java.
My question is

**Is it possible to retrieve this data ( i.e. xyz) from localhost server  using AJAX/JQuery to JavaScript????**

What function does that and how do we do that ?? Plz show me with example..it will be very great help for me

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is something just like common HTTP requests, but it is sent inside your jvascript code and can be moderate with javascript.

Independent of the server side script you have, you can use Ajax to send requests and get responses from that server side application (In server side it can be treated as a simple HTTP reauest).

Finally this is a helpful toturial: [W3School Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) , and if you are familiar with JQuery or using it in your current project, it is the reference for JQuery Ajax: [JQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), both with samples.